# Monday falls on 20th March, 1995. What was the day on 3rd November, 1994?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, calendar-computations

> Monday falls on 20th March, 1995. What was the day on 3rd November, 1994?

Days in November 1994( starting from 3rd)= $27$
Days in December 1994=$31$
Days in January 1995=$31$
Days in February 1995= $28$
Days in March 1995= $31$
$27+31+31+28+20= 137$
 DIviding 137 by 7, I got number of odd days as 4. Now what next?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "20th March falls on a Monday"?

Comment: It was a [thursday](http://www.onthisday.com/date/1994/november/3), indeed.

Comment: $137=7*19+4$, i.e. 19 weeks and 4 days. So starting on the Monday 20th, you have to go back 19 weeks (which will still be a Monday) and then 4 days further back.

Comment: I guess if you had a access to a perpetual calendar, but I don't think that is likely.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

If the remainder is $0$, it is a Monday.

If the remainder is $1$, it is a Sunday.

If the remainder is $2$, it is a Saturday.

I believe you can complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is effective-enough for you: leap years must be divisible by 4, so 1994 was not a leap year. Now we just need to know the number of days in each month $Mod7$:  November has $30=2$, December has $31=3$, Jan $=31=3$, $Feb=28=0$ . Then , December $3$ carries $2$, January $3$ carries $2+3$, February 3 carries $2+3+3=1$ , and March $3$ carries $2+3+3=1 $ , So March $2$ is the same day of the week as November $3$ , so March $20$ is $18=4$ days ahead of November $3$. Since March $20$ is a Monday, November $3$ was on a Thursday.